# Getting error message with Search on arXiv electronic preprint database

Tags: dataset, data-acquisition

Just installed *Mathematica* v10.3 which has the new option to use arXiv, the electronic database. However I get an error message using

```
arXiv = ServiceConnect["ArXiv"]

articles = arXiv["Search", {"Query" -> "Title" -> "Quantum" | "Cavity", "MaxItems" -> 4}]

(*  The parameter Search  is not available for the service ArXiv . *)
```

I wonder whether this is specific to my machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I got the same error message. Using the menu bar Edit ► Preferences... and clicking the "Update Local Indices from Wolfram Research Server" button under the Internet Connectivity tab fixed this erroneous behavior.

Comment: Worked, once you restart MMA ver 10.3. thanks

Comment: @thils I just had to reevaluate `arXiv = ServiceConnect["ArXiv"]`.

Comment: @thils  I simply ran your code, received the message that Mathematica was updating from the Wolfram server, and then I received the desired results.  No fuss.  Who knows why this works on one machine and not another?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I guess the automatic updates took care of it on your machine.